# How can I copy sqlite file to other drive?

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I need help, how can I copy sqlite file to other drive using VB.Net. Sqlite file contains in release folder of the project. So I want to copy sqlite file from release folder to other drive using VB.Net.

Comment: Close the connection and use `IO.File.Copy`.

Comment: @muffi can you write code here in answer?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=netframework-4.8